# VM inside an Esxi host does not have Internet access

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, bridge-router

I have installed an ESXi 6.7 host inside a VMware Workstation.  That ESXi has one VM Ubuntu 20 server running. But that VM does not have internet access.
Here are the network settings:

- ESXi host is connected to internet router via Bridged adapter option in VMware Workstation.
- ESXi host has IP address 192.168.10.22 automatically given to it by my router which is accessible by my
  other devices on same home network. (e.g. I can login to ESXi from another laptop with the IP)
- VM (Ubuntu server) is connected to the default port group 'VM Network'
- VM Network port group is connected to default vSwitch which has vmnic0 physical adapter of ESXi host.

Now all the settings are pretty much default as it comes with fresh ESXi installation. But when I check the network settings inside the Ubuntu Server VM there is no IP address like it should have IP e.g 192.168.10.30 by DHCP server. I can see the Ethernet adapter called "ens160" in the Ubuntu VM but there is no IP given to it by the DHCP of my router and hence there is no internet and neither i am able to access it locally from my other network machines.
I already tried giving static IP manually to my Ubuntu VM but no ping to internet websites or even local network machines.

How can I make such settings so that my Ubuntu server VM also has direct IP assigned by DHCP of my router just like my ESXi host.

All the help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you solve your problem? I'm having the same and can't find any solution. It would be great if you could share your solution here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem I was having, which looks quite similar to the one described here.

It happened on an old IBM server with an IMM2 interface (this is the first of four network interfaces). The IMM2 is represented as a vusb0 adapter. This adapter was attached to vSwitch0, too, together with vmnic0. Looking at the "Failover order" configuration of the vSwitch, the vmnic0 was the active one and the vmnic0 only in standby status. Removing vusb0 from the switch solved the problem (maybe it would be sufficient to just change the order).